# Groovy/Grails Mapping Error Unknown column 'class' in 'field list'

Tags: grails, groovy

Recently I've started with Groovy and Grails but I'm having the following error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>           Unknown column 'class' in 'field list'
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)

But my Entity and its mother doesn't have class attribute
See there's no class field but on MySQL insert somehow its present

```
class Freight extends Base {

String codeBegin
String codeEnd
BigDecimal weight
BigDecimal value
BigDecimal minValue
FreightRange range

Integer time

FreightType type
String name
Integer leadTime
BigDecimal realFreightValue
String realFreightName
FreightType realFreightType
Manufacturer manufacturer

static embedded = ['range']

static transients = ['type', 'name', 'leadTime', 'realFreightValue', 'realFreightName', 'realFreightType', 'manufacturer']

static belongsTo = [partnerFreightType: PartnerFreightType]

static mapping = {
    version false
}

static constraints = {
    codeBegin nullable: true, blank: true, validator: Freight.rangeValidator
    codeEnd nullable: true, blank: true, validator: Freight.rangeValidator
    weight nullable: false, min: BigDecimal.valueOf(0.001)
    value nullable: false, min: BigDecimal.valueOf(0), max: BigDecimal.valueOf(9999.99)
    minValue nullable: false, min: BigDecimal.valueOf(0)
    range nullable: true
    time nullable: true
}

static rangeValidator = { val, obj ->
    if (obj.codeBegin?.replace('-', '')?.toInteger() > obj.codeEnd?.replace('-', '')?.toInteger())
        return 'freight.error.range'
}

String getHash() {
    (this.partnerFreightType + this.type + this.value).encodeAsMD5()
}


void useRange(FreightRange range) {
    this.range = range

    def codes = range.codes()

    this.codeBegin = codes.min
    this.codeEnd = codes.max
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the code for 'Base' as well?

Comment: When does this error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a class hierarchy, there must be way (called discriminator) for the ORM to know what class to instantiate when fetching a row from your table.

From GORM documentation : "At the database level GORM by default uses table-per-hierarchy mapping with a discriminator column called class so the parent class (Content) and its subclasses (BlogEntry, Book etc.), share the same table."

see http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#inheritanceInGORM